# Bootstrap carousel elements how to decrease the built-in width of the section

Tags: python, html, css, web, bootstrap-5

The 1st image is [here](https://ibb.co/b5xKDRj)

And the 2nd image is [here](https://freeimage.host/i/HJasdWQ)

This is the carousel code of website.

```
<div class="row testing">
  <div id="carouselExampleMen" class="carousel carousel-dark slide" data-bs-ride="carousel">
    <div class="carousel-inner mens-section">
      <div class="carousel-item active" data-bs-interval="10000">
        <img src="fashion/men1.png" class="d-block w-100 " alt="...">
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item" data-bs-interval="2000">
        <img src="fashion/men2.png" class="d-block w-100 " alt="...">
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <img src="fashion/men3.png" class="d-block w-100 " alt="...">
      </div>
      <button class="carousel-control-prev" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleMen" data-bs-slide="prev">
        <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="visually-hidden">Previous</span>
      </button>
      <button class="carousel-control-next" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleMen" data-bs-slide="next">
        <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="visually-hidden">Next</span>
      </button>
      <div class="carousel-indicators">
        <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleMen" data-bs-slide-to="0" class="active" aria-current="true" aria-label="Slide 1"></button>
        <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleMen" data-bs-slide-to="1" aria-label="Slide 2"></button>
        <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleMen" data-bs-slide-to="2" aria-label="Slide 3"></button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You are in a `row` so you are supposed to use a `col-x` class to set your items width

Comment: col-x gives me this result:   https://ibb.co/TtN3kVZ    now, with row I have this  
  https://ibb.co/dcPVLBy   I only want to remove built in width but whe i trying to use width it decrease the whole section including image of carousel.

Comment: Do you have any question about this code? What have you tried to resolve the problem? How is this related to Python?

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by overwriting its class:

```html
.testing {
  width: 100%;
}
.carousel-inner{
  width:50%;
  max-height: 200px !important;
}
```

change the width percentage as you like
and of course, you can use media queries for different screen sizes

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 488px) {}
```

Comment: thank brother I reached to the expected result  https://ibb.co/H7dcDPc with only using this.

Comment: .testing {
  width: 100%;
}
.carousel-inner{
  width:100%;
  max-height: 1000px !important;
}

Comment: cool, good luck with your project